# ValueError: Sample larger than population selecting samples from graph

Tags: python, random, sample

I am trying to randomly select n samples from a graph. In order to do so I create a list called X using the random.sample function like the following:

```
X= random.sample(range(graph.ecount()), numPosSamples)
```

The problem is that when numPosSamples is equal to graph.ecount() I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Sample larger than population
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how `numPosSamples` is getting its value, but because `random.sample` does sampling *without* replacement, what is probably happening here is that `numPosSamples` is greater than the number of edges in your graph.  As a result, Python raises the `ValueError` that you are seeing.

Either reduce the number of samples to less than the number of edges, or use a method of sampling that allows for sampling *with* replacement, such as a list comprehension with `random.choice`.

Comment: You were right. I was making a mistake passing the first argument of the sample function. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add some logic that detects if your list if shorter than the number of samples you want.

For example:

```
a = list(range(10))
num_samples = 20
sample(a, num_samples if len(a) > num_samples else len(a))
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `sample(a, min(num_samples, len(a)))`